# Font with an ant as a symbol

Tags: fonts

Do you know of some font which has an ant as a character?  (I need it in a document I'm preparing in plain tex that is to be processed by pdftex.)

Comment: My suggestion: (1) Pick an [and from OpenClipArt](https://openclipart.org/search/?query=ant); (2) Import SVG into [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/); (3) Export as PDF image; (4) Include image in TeX.

Comment: @Werner.  What's the pdftex command for including a pdf?

Comment: http://www.fontspace.com/willymac/wminsects1

Comment: http://www.fontspace.com/shadowy-mist/lpinsects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the answer about the `ant` font, but how to load the external image with `\pdfximage`, query its dimensions with `\pdfrefximage` and use it finally with `\pdflastximage`, all in a box, then unbox it (see `pdftex` manual for this)

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\pdfximage{beeduck.jpg}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}
\unhbox0
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: @User: No worries. It's a CW - answer anyway